# スプレッドシートからJSONデータを取得できなくなった

Tags: php, json, google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートをJSON形式で公開するアドレス
'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1jWXAB7BHyuEecx3L7o5KWp-qceeO0k5q5sJDtHUDRo0/2/public/values?alt=json'

上記のような方法で、json形式のデータをphpのfile_get_contensで取得できていたのですが、最近できなくなりました。

Comment: 質問文に記載されているものは [`Google Sheets v3 API`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3) と呼ばれるWeb API のようですが、`2021-08-02`  に提供が終了したため、代わりに [`v4`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)を使う必要があるようです。([移行ガイド](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration))

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 ありがとうございます。v4に対応するように修正しようと思います。